# Is there a way to hide forks in Azure Devops repos?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

The repo list in Azure devops is kinda long for us, we have about 25 different repos to maintain.

Multiply that with 10+ team members and you get 225 repos to "browse"

How can you hide the forks

Comment: There's no need for individuals to fork repos to develop. Just have them create branches on the same repo and use PRs to manage merges.

Comment: @DanielMann you should post that as an Answer, because it seems like the right advice to me

Answer (score 2):

You can hide forked repos by changing the RBAC settings for the repo so that it's not visible to people that shouldn't be able to see it.

However, there is no need for individuals to fork repos to develop. It's an unnecessary extra step in the development process.

Just let developers create branches on the repo that everyone is currently forking and use PRs to manage merges to protected branches.